# Clear boot messages and open terminal on TTY1

Tags: boot, 18.04, tty, dmesg

I updated from Ubuntu Server 16.04 to 18.04 and after all other configuration fixing was done there is still one thing bugging me:

On my previous version, after booting, the `[   OK   ]` messages would disappear and a terminal would start on what I think was tty1. I could simply login and continue or leave it and the screen would turn off automatically.

This doesn't happen anymore. tty1 remains showing the boot messages and I can only access terminals on tty2 through tty6. Does anyone know how to open a terminal on tty1 after booting is complete, or switch to tty2 automatically?

My servers' display won't turn off if it remains on the boot status messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

For some reason `getty@tty1.service` was disabled in systemd

So all I had to do was

`# systemctl enable getty@tty1.service`